# How can I check to see if some coordinates are inside the UK?

Tags: r, latitude-longitude

I got Latitude and longitude data. I want to check if this coordinates are inside UK or not? example code specially using R are appreciated.

Comment: for you my answer is google maps :)

Comment: that closing link is one of _many_ on SO that you could have used. pls do basic research in the future

Answer (score 0):

package RDSTK::coordinates2politics

[link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RDSTK/RDSTK.pdf)

please use a websearch before posting here

Comment: Thank you Marcel. That is what I was looking for. @Andre-I got millions of rows of Lat/Lng and was looking for something that can be automated.